# What does expected value "given the data distribution" mean?

Tags: sampling, expected-value

I am reading [this tuorial](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~ojw/files/NotesOnCD.pdf) on constrastive divergence and at the end of **page 2** they define the *expectation given the data*. I am unclear on what this means? How is this different from regular expected value?

Comment: Maybe they just mean the empirical mean?

Comment: of the sample ?

Comment: It would be helpful to put the relevant equations in the question. In general "expected value given the data" would refer to a combination of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability).

Comment: If I have found the part you mean, you misquote what it says there. It doesn't say "given the data" it says "given the data distribution". The distinction is important.

Comment: What is the distinction

Answer (score 0):

In that context, it is still referring to a population mean.

The distribution F(X) in the question has population parameter vector $\Theta$. It's just a nonstandard notation.